# PostGIS Intersect to update a field based on intersected State

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, spatial, spatial-query

I'll admit I'm a little out of my element with PostGIS and spatial geometries in a DB but here's what I'm after: I need to update a field with the determined intersected US State of a geom of an object if it doesn't yet already have one.

The DB structure is as follows:

**Accomplishment**

| id | name | phys_state | poly_point_line_id (fk Accomplishment_Feature) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test Accomp 1 | AK | 123 |
| 2 | Test Accomp 2 |  | 456 |
| 3 | Test Accomp 3 |  | 789 |

**Accomplishment_Feature** (technically not needed in the query AFAIK but included here just in case since it is a join table between the Accomplishment and its geometry types)

| id |
| --- |
| 123 |
| 456 |
| 789 |

**Accoomplishment_Poly**

| id (fk to Accomplishment_Feature) | geom |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | [multipolygon geometry] |

**Accoomplishment_Line**

| id (fk to Accomplishment_Feature) | geom |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | [multiline geometry] |

**Accoomplishment_Point**

| id (fk to Accomplishment_Feature) | geom |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | [multipoint geometry] |

I need to determine the intersected US state of each of the geoms for Accomplishments that don't have a value in the `physical_state` column.

I currently have a table of US State geometries in another schema that I can use.

I currently have the following but it errors out and I'm obviously misunderstanding how to write the queries.

```
UPDATE accomplishment a
SET a.phys_state = us_state.abbrev
FROM support_gis.state_g us_state
LEFT JOIN accomplishment_poly poly on a.poly_point_line_id = poly.id
WHERE st_intersects(st_centroid(poly.geom), us_state.geom) AND a.phys_state is null
```

Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hey there. Do you need to check the intersection of the geometry or its centroid?

Comment: *"I currently have the following but it errors out"* what does the error look like? can you also provide a sample of the geometries?

Comment: @JimJones my thought was to use the centroid of the Accomplishment geom to determine the intersection of the US State in case the geom crosses boundaries of more than 1 state.

The errors are SQL syntax errors I'm currently working through but this is the one I'm getting now using the query in the post:
*SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "a"
  Hint: There is an entry for table "a", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How the `FROM` clause in an `UPDATE` statement works is slightly different than in a `SELECT` - go figure. An alternative is to go old school: just put all involved tables in the `FROM` clause and solve the joins in the `WHERE` clause instead using `JOIN`s.

```
UPDATE accomplishment 
SET phys_state = us_state.abbrev
FROM support_gis.state_g us_state, accomplishment_poly poly
WHERE 
  ST_Intersects(ST_Centroid(poly.geom), us_state.geom) AND 
  phys_state IS NULL AND
  poly_point_line_id = poly.id;
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems to be exactly what I needed! Sorry for the late reply; got pulled off to assist in other issue and then we started having network issues. Only thing I had to add was the accomplishment table to the FROM declaration because the query didn't like it without! Thanks again!